# jQuery UI Dynamic Tab Content Styles Not Working

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, codeigniter, jquery-ui-tabs

I set the href of each tab to be "controller/method" so that it will display in the tab.
It really went great for the contents to load in the tab but as I set the styles of the html table (sample content that came from controller/method) and it doesn't work.

```
Below is the screenshot of the tab loaded via ajax.
```

[image]

```
Here is the result if the method is directly access from the URL.
```

[image]

Question: Why does the table don't appear to be the same when loaded via ajax?

Comment: Cos Jquery UI CSS is over-riding the default table styles ...

Comment: Hard to say without seeing your code or a working example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Already solved this problem.

I placed the css in the main page thus, making the dynamic content acquire the styles.